# how to stop event "Change" propagation in slider jquery object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I need to understand how can I stop an event propagation, in particular the "change" propagation of a slider. normally, in my application, change is called when

- I move the slider directly on the bar;
- I change the slider position with this command `$("#idPlayerSlider").slider("value", nNewPosition);` somewhere in my code.

this is the slider:

```
$("#idPlayerSlider").slider({
  orientation: "horizontal",
  range: "min",
  max: nPlayerTime,
  value: PLAYER_VIEW.TIMESTAMP_TOTAL,
  change: seekPlayerVideo
});
```

this is the operation I do to change the slider value:

```
$("#idPlayerSlider").slider("value", nNewPosition);
```

the question is: is there a way to stop change propagation when I set the new value of the slider? because I need the change callback is called when I move it on the real slider, but if I force a new value i would like this callback is not called anymore.
so the need is to stop its propagation.
how can I do?
thank you in advance.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/ ?

Comment: i know about this command, but how to set it in the context of my scenario? that's because before i call `$("#idPlayerSlider").slider("value", nNewPosition);` i don't have the `event` which propagation need to be stopped. i can't call it after, because i still don't have the `event` variable, and at that time the event is already happenned. i need to manage the event _change_ of the [slider object](http://jqueryui.com/slider/)

Comment: can you show me an example?

Comment: Try refering to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255041/jquery-slider-change-event-how-do-i-determine-who-called-it

Comment: I'll have a look, thank you.