# How to stop programmatically event on original event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, seekbar

I have a slider in my webpage which is used to visualize the progress of an audio playback.

If the playback progress is moving on, I programatically change the position of the slider. Now if the user change the position manually, I have the problem to recognize whether it's a user driven action or if the slider event comes from my programatically change.

How can I find out whether the user was responsible for the slide event?

Comment: it's kind of hard to track whether it's a user driven actiopn or it's something you did in your code.
I guess, my first try would be to track whether you have a mousedown event on your slider. if so and the slider is, you could stop the playback and listen for drag events of the mouse.

Comment: I am also thinking in this way only

Comment: [Same situation that i am facing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255041/jquery-slider-change-event-how-do-i-determine-who-called-it)

Comment: Well this is awesome. Didn't know about this property. Thank you!